# The type 'Autofac.Builder.ReflectionActivatorData' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, autofac

I've got a solution containing multiple C# projects, some of which are using Autofac. If I add a reference to an Autofac-using project to an existing project, I get the following error message when compiling my solution:

```
The type 'Autofac.Builder.ReflectionActivatorData' is defined in an assembly that
is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
'Autofac, Version=2.6.3.862, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'.
```

However, the project where the error is raised isn't directly using Autofac, the other project already has a reference, and (most confusingly) the line where the error message is raised has got nothing to do with Autofac -- it doesn't mention any Autofac types; it doesn't mention any types that might have been registered with Autofac.

What's going on? I can fix it by adding a reference to Autofac, but I don't want to, *because this project doesn't use Autofac*.

And, once I've added a reference to Autofac, to get it to compile, Reflector shows me that the resulting binary *doesn't have* a direct reference to Autofac, because it's not used. I get the same results in dotPeek and NDepend.

I've only seen this problem with Autofac, by the way.

Comment: Perhaps you should reference Autofac in that project?

Comment: I don't want to -- it doesn't use Autofac.

Comment: I've never seen this error pop up in cases where the compiler was wrong. Take a good look at that line of code where the error is pointing. There is probably a type in their that either inherits from `ReflectionActivatorData` or exposes the `ReflectionActivatorData` as a public or protected property, method argument or return value (or something similar).

Comment: There definitely isn't. I've looked. I've also confirmed this by checking that Reflector, dotPeek and NDepend all show that there are no references to Autofac in the binary.

Comment: How did you check that there are no references if it won't compile?

Comment: When I add the references to get the compiler to shut up, and then take a look, there are no references in the resulting binary.